# Bootstrap: FIxed div height of parent element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.2 in my application.
I am wrapping two col-md-6 in a row.

One column is having a some content. The other col is empty
I want the other column to be of same height as the col that is having some text
The height should be fixed height with scroll bar.
I can't set the height manually as height can change

See the attached screen shot

[image: Fixed height]

Comment: `The height should be fixed height with scroll bar` What does it mean while you are stating `I can't set the height manually as height can change`, Fixed height or vary height?

Comment: the use case is as i type into content i will render it into second div so if content is more there should be scroll bars

Comment: Couldn't you use a `min-height` and also `overflow-y: auto;` for both elements?

Comment: @HashemQolami No I can't use that because there are would be so many div like this

Answer (score 1):

Use col-md-12 instead of col-md-6

```
<style>
    .table tr td{width:50%;}
</style>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Your text
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/vxP9vBfzwH)

```
  var height = $("#Col1")[0].clientHeight;
  $("#Col2").css('height', height + 'px');
```

Comment: Isn't there any bootstrap classes to automatically set the height.
I assume this should be in built in bootstrap

Comment: If I have this situation in multiple places I have to use this script at every place that is not feasible

Comment: I think there is no options in bootstrap